# \chemdelta not works with ctex in LaTeX

Tags: chemmacros, ctex

I find when I compile with `ctex` package in LaTeX, the `\chemdelta` is missing.
For example:
[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chemmacros,ctex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\chemdelta\isotope*{2,H}}
你好 \chemdelta\isotope*{2,H}
\end{document}
```

I can't imagine the reason that will cause this problem. There is even not an error.

Comment: you would get an error if you used `\tracinglostchars=3`.  ctex loads fontspec and there the delta only works directly if you use a text font which has the symbol.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay. So it is very important to use a font which contains all symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally just `\usepackage{upgreek}` or `\usepackage{textgreek}` will do
as an implicit mapping, as is mentioned in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros-manual.pdf).

However with `ctex` package loaded, an explicit mapping is required, for example
`\chemsetup{greek=upgreek}`.

[image: Manual1]
[image: Manual2]

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I use `upgreek` package, the delta symbol will be tilt. Is there a way to set it upright?

Comment: It seems that `\chemsetup{greek=upgreek}` is necessary when `ctex` is loaded. I will edit my answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: I see if no `\usepackage{upgreek}`,  just only `\chemsetup{greek=upgreek}` will work.

Comment: Indeed it seems so, even simpler :-)

Comment: Do you fell LaTex a little difficult to understand? How can I have a systematic and clear understanding of latex?

Comment: Well, I feel that I cannot write good LaTeX code without TEX.SX. Occasionally checking the package manual is also needed. I just got accustomed to the search-when-I-have-problem workflow. The charm of LaTeX gradually reveals itself to me whenever I discover a new solution.

Comment: Yes! I have the same feeling as you!